# I want to read only document names in an existing collection and show it in drop down list using cloud firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want highlighted documents to display in drop down

[image: data structure pic]

Comment: So, what have you done so far, and what is the issue you're facing?